# Devexpress mvc extensions. Whether these extensions are server side or client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I am a asp.net developer and going to work on MVC 4. I want to use devexpress mvc extensions for my application. Now I want to know whether these extensions are server side or client side? Also what are the problems while upgrading the same. Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer after downloading trial Version of DevExpress. Here some brief notes for beginner with DevExpress..

Is MVC Extension control library a server side control library or a client side JQuery library ?

-->This is a server-side library. In addition, a client-side control library (DXTREME) that can be used as an alternative.

1. Compatibility of the DevExpress MVC Extension with MVC 4.0 ?

-->Extensions are compatible with MVC4.

1. Compatibility of MVC Extension with .Net Framework 4.5 ?

--> Compatible with .NET Framework 4.0. They can be successfully used in a .NET Framework 4.5 environment. However, they do not use
4.5 Framework features for the above mentioned reason.

1. Any performance pointers on the MVC Extension control library ?

--> Products performance (http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18541). The most part of suggestions make sense in MVC too. In addition, the MVC GridView component has Custom Data Binding mode that will be useful in case of binding to a large custom data source.

1. Compatibility of MVC Extension with different devices ex: Mobile and ipads ?

--> Support several mobile device browsers.

1. Compatibility of MVC Extension control library with Angular JS / Backbone JS/ KnockOut JS ?

--> No guarantee compatibility of MVC extensions with these tools (Pass in some and fails in some cases). DXTREME is fully compatible with Knockout JS.

1. Facility in MVC Extension to communicate with the web services using JSON/String/XML ?

--> Components are server-side components and require data communication with an MVC  server. The server can communicate to third-party services, however, ASP.NET MVC components cannot do so directly. DXTREME components support data binding to web services.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by "are server side or client side".

It is not a pure Javascript library. They use features of the MVC framework in order to do their magic, so I'd say they are both (but not just one side). More specifically, they implement custom controls that you include in your views. The controls have settings and such that you set on server side. However, the code generated relies on Javascript so they run on the client (using ajax calls when necessary).

See documentation and examples here: [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8161)